# How to properly write an if condition inside assert?

Tags: dart

```dart
f({bool b, String s}) {
  assert(b ? s != null : true);
}
```

Is there any better way to write the above `assert` based on the condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *always* rewrite a boolean conditional expression (`?`-`:`) where one branch is a boolean literal, into a combination of `||`, `&&` and `!`.

```
| Bad conditional | Good and/or |
|-----------------|-------------|
|  b ? true : v   |  b || v     |
|  b ? false : v  |  !b && v    |
|  b ? v : true   |  !b || v    |
|  b ? v : false  |  b && v     |
```

So, in your case: `assert(!b || s != null);`